# Android Timer executing earlier then specified period

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am using a code to show a notification every hour to the user based on certain conditions. I am learning so the most basic code is here.

```
Log.v("Service Started", "onStartCommand");
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.v("Show Notification", "Showing notification at "+System.currentTimeMillis());
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
                Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SplashScreen.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),123,intent1,0);
                Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                        .setContentTitle("Dimensions Weather & News")
                        .setContentText("Thank you for using our app.")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
                        .setVibrate(pattern)
                        .setSound(alarmSound)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).getNotification();

                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notificationManager.notify(123, notification);
            }
        }, 0, 3600000);
```

But it shows notifications every now and then and not on interval of an hour. Most of the times it shows at 6-7 minutes after the previous one. Why?

Comment: dont use Timer/TimerTask in android apps,  use AlarmManager instead

Answer (score 0):

TimerTask is depend System’s time，use AlarmManager instand it.

Comment: Even if it does depend on system time, I am not changing it. 3600000 ms should confirm notification every hour.